# gdb cannot watch variables declared inside for-loop

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I am using
gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-23.el5_5.1)

and I cannot watch variables declared inside for-loop. I tried to recreate this behavior on a smaller example but it worked fine. Seems like this problem shows up only inside complex class member functions. Please, advise.

EDIT: optimizations are turned off

Comment: Have you turned *off* optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to solve it exactly but this work around might help you.

Let us say want to access  loop variable in

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){...}
```

You could do the following

```
print &i
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdfa8
watch *0x7fffffffdfa8
```

This one has the definite disadvantage of having to wait as it may get reassigned garbage values multiple number of times,and each time it happens you get a notification

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you compiled with optimizations on. Try recompiling with with `-O0 -g`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you probably need to turn off optimizations.  The *why* is because the compiler likely eliminated the local variables during the optimization step and stored their values directly in a register.

You might also try declaring these variables as *volatile* while testing, if you don't wish to re-build everything with -O0.